# Phyton error "arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type" - but I need floats

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a problem of getting this mistake, but I can't find a way to simply use `dtype=np.int8` or something like that because all the `arrays` need `precise floats`.

I am currently working on a simple model of `covid-19 infection spreading`. I decided to try with many `numpy arrays` that have impact on each other. I have `np.array` of `np.zeros arrays` and in every one of those `arrays of array`, I want to `replace the first zero`. Each time, the new number is different from the previous ones, because it's always a different share of infected people (it's always about shares, that's why I need precise floats). I take these different shares from the other `np.array`. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
Shares = np.array([0.327, 0.246, 0.183, 0.1575, 0.054, 0.022, 0.007, 0.002, 0.0011, 0.0004])
nND = np.array([gD1, gD2, gD3, gD4, gD5, gD6, gD7, gD8, gD9, gD10]) #these gDx are all 1D np.zeros(366) arrays
for a in nND:
    nND[a][0] = (Shares[a] * (a+1)/2300000)
```

I have read loops aren't the best way to deal with np.arrays as well. However, I don't know how efficient python lists would be. I am sorry if there is some kind of an obvious mistake, I am very new to the field.

Thank you for your help,
Ana

Comment: "but I need floats"—then you need a different data structure. (Are you _sure_ you need floats as your _indexes_? Not your _values_?)

Comment: You need to study basic Python more; even with lists the use of `for a in nND: nND[a]...` does not make sense.  Learn what a simple `for i in alist:` does.  While your `Shares` array is clear, the `nND` is not.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you meant. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use...

```
a[0] = (Shares[a] * (a+1)/2300000)
```

...instead of...

```
nND[a][0] = (Shares[a] * (a+1)/2300000)
```

... because a is already nNd[whatever element you are currently on on in the for loop]. So a isn't a number, but nND[0] or nND[1], and so on...

Comment: Thank you, Jackson, I see, a wasn't even a number. Thanks a lot!